# Partial Derivative of sums of vector with respect to another

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, machine-learning

What is the derivative, with respect to w, of

$\lambda_1y_1X_1w + \lambda_2y_2X_2w + ... \lambda_ny_nX_nw$

Where $y_i$ and $\lambda_i$ are constants, $X_i$ is 1 by n, and w is n by 1?

My first thought was that it was the sum of the $\lambda_iy_iX_i$ (factoring out w), but this didn't make sense to me because w is not in the front of the expression, and this creates a "sum" of 1 by n matrices, which didn't make sense.

Comment: any thoughts or attempts about the question?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus has all you need to answer this question. Have you already read this page in its entirety?

Comment: I couldn't really parse the notation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider a simpler example.
Namely, consider taking the derivative of
$$
f(x)=ca^{\intercal}x
$$
where $c$ is a constant, $a$ is a vector, and $x$ is a vector.
Note that we can rewrite the above as
$$
f(x)=c\sum_{i}a_{i}x_{i}.
$$
Now that we have gotten rid of the vector notation, the problem can be solved using ordinary calculus.
In particular,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{j}}(x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left[c\sum_{i}a_{i}x_{i}\right]=c\sum_{i}a_{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}\left[x_{i}\right]=ca_{j}.
$$
Putting this back into vector notation,
$$
\nabla f(x)=ca.
$$
See if you can apply the same idea to your problem.

---

**Note**: it would have also been valid to conclude $$\nabla f(x)=ca^\intercal.$$
This depends on the [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) you choose to use.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** If $L$ is a linear continuous function, then it is differentiable at every $w$ and $L'(w)=L.$